# Finding the opposite of a query

Tags: postgresql

Question: Which regions (use names) did not have any employment in 'Mining and Logging'?

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT region.name AS region_name
FROM region INNER JOIN division ON region.number=division.region_number
INNER JOIN state ON division.number=state.division_number 
INNER JOIN blse ON state.state=blse.state
WHERE industry != 'Mining and Logging';
```

Above is the code I am running and it isn't displaying what I want. There are 9 total industries, and 5 seperate regions. The answer should be 1 region ('Other'), but the code above displays all the regions since all the regions have other industries. If I run the code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT region.name AS region_name
FROM region INNER JOIN division ON region.number=division.region_number
INNER JOIN state ON division.number=state.division_number 
INNER JOIN blse ON state.state=blse.state
WHERE industry = 'Mining and Logging';
```

I get a total of 4 regions with 'Other' not being there because 'Mining and Logging' isn't an industry in that region. How do I get just 'Other'? I basically need the opposite results of this query, but I'm stumped. For the 'Other' region 'Mining and Logging' isn't listed as an industry so I'm trying to get the right query to find all regions with no 'Mining and Logging' listed.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: `SELECT region.name AS region_name FROM region WHERE EXISTS( ... );`

Comment: `SELECT region.name AS region_name FROM region WHERE NOT EXISTS( ... );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT region.name AS region_name
FROM region INNER JOIN division ON region.number=division.region_number
INNER JOIN state ON division.number=state.division_number 
INNER JOIN blse ON state.state=blse.state
WHERE industry != 'Mining and Logging'
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT region.name AS region_name
FROM region INNER JOIN division ON region.number=division.region_number
INNER JOIN state ON division.number=state.division_number 
INNER JOIN blse ON state.state=blse.state
WHERE industry = 'Mining and Logging';
```

Comment: DISTINCT is always a red flag. Why not just use (not) EXISTS( ... ) ?